# Stuck with JavaFX GUI, how to draw/print after each state/calculation?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am working on a GUI for a game of life implementation using javaFX. I am trying to draw each generation on the canvas after a one second delay, but my code does not do that. What happens is it gets a random zero generation, waits a second, generates the first generation, then waits another second generates the next one, and so on until it reaches the determined number of generations. Then after this whole proccess is done it draws the last generation only. I tried some experimenting with no luck, and now I am out of ideas. How can I get the program to draw after the calculatiion of each generation?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class gui extends Application {

    /////////////////////GUI SETUP PART/////////////////////////////////////////////

    public int SquareSize = 16;
    public int oldgrid [][];
    public int newgrid [][];
    public int ngens=5;
    public int width = 10;
    public int height = 10;
    public int currentgen = 0;
    public Group root;  

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Game of Life");
        root = new Group();
        oldgrid = new int [height][width];
        newgrid = new int [height][width];
        randomize();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500, 500);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        run(gc);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void draw(GraphicsContext gc)
    {
        for(int y =0 ; y < getY() ; y++ )
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < getX() ; x++)
            {
                if(oldgrid[y][x] == 0)
                {
                    gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                    gc.fillRect(x*SquareSize, y*SquareSize, SquareSize, SquareSize);
                }
                else if(oldgrid[y][x] == 1)
                {
                    gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                    gc.fillRect(x*SquareSize, y*SquareSize, SquareSize, SquareSize);
                }
            }
        }

    }




    ////////////////////game of life rules part////////////////////////
    public int getcurrentgen() {
        return currentgen;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return oldgrid[0].length;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return oldgrid.length;
    }

    int Neighbours(int x, int y) //calculating neighbours
    {
        int neighbours = 0;

        if (x > 0 && oldgrid[y][x - 1] == 1) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        if (x < getX() - 1 && oldgrid[y][x + 1] == 1) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        if (y < getY() - 1 && x > 0 && oldgrid[y + 1][x - 1] == 1) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        if (y < getY() - 1 && x < getX() - 1 && oldgrid[y + 1][x + 1] == 1) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        if (y < getY() - 1 && oldgrid[y + 1][x] == 1) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        if (y > 0 && x > 0 && oldgrid[y - 1][x - 1] == 1) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        if (y > 0 && x < getX() - 1 && oldgrid[y - 1][x + 1] == 1) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        if (y > 0 && oldgrid[y - 1][x] == 1) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        return neighbours;
    }

    public void setup() // applying the rules
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < getY(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < getX(); x++) {

                if (oldgrid[y][x] == 1) {
                    if (Neighbours(x, y) < 2) {
                        newgrid[y][x] = 0;
                    }
                    if (Neighbours(x, y) > 3) {
                        newgrid[y][x] = 0;
                    }
                    if (Neighbours(x, y) == 3 || Neighbours(x, y) == 2) {
                        newgrid[y][x] = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (oldgrid[y][x] == 0) {
                    if (Neighbours(x, y) == 3) {
                        newgrid[y][x] = 1;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }

    public void run(GraphicsContext gc)
    {
        draw(gc);
        while(currentgen < ngens)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            setup();
            for (int y = 0; y < getY(); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < getX(); x++) {
                    oldgrid[y][x] = newgrid[y][x];
                }
            }
            currentgen++;
            draw(gc);
        }
    }

    public void randomize() {

        // randomizing dead(0) and live(1) cells
        for (int y = 0; y < getY(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < getX(); x++) {
                double tmp = Math.random();
                if (tmp < 0.5) {
                    oldgrid[y][x] = 0;
                } else {
                    oldgrid[y][x] = 1;
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider writing a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to avoid irrelevant code clutter.

Comment: You are invoking your `run()` method on the FX Application Thread; this prevents any UI updates until that method has completed. You need to read up on multithreading in JavaFX ([tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm#JFXIP546), [`Task` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/concurrent/Task.html)). As it stands your question really boils down to "How and why should I implement multithreading in JavaFX", which is too broad for this forum. Read the linked docs, try to implement something, and ask again if stuck.